# using custom JRE in android Studio

Tags: java, java-9, jlink

I just read some new features of Java 9. There is a concept Jlink through which we can create a custom JRE and can use the path of that custom JRE in java command while running a class.

So I am curious to know that how can I use that custom JRE in android studio or any Editor like Eclipse.

Comment: I highly doubt that `jlink` is integrated with any of the IDEs as of now. As for the question its off-topic for SO. *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: Can you explain what actual goal you want to achieve with that?